# Bitwise binary overflow at less than 0-255, e.g. 0-32?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, bit-manipulation

I use unsigned byte's 0-255 binary overflow / wraparound, as this saves on certain bounds checks (conditional branches) in a infinitely wrapping game world.

**Is there a way, using bit operators, to wrap on an arbitrary power-of-2 value, e.g. 2^5 = 32?**

This would happen non-conditionally, so that if the value were >= 32, we'd wrap as usual, and if it were < 32, the value would remain the same.

Comment: The modular operator is not fast enough?

Comment: @Tarik Modulo is one of the most costly arithmetic operations, comparable to divide.

Comment: did not know. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Engineer Modulo on exactly power of 2 minus 1 will be fast on most processors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can just and the value with a mask. So if you want your value modulo 32 you can do

```
x = x & 31;
```

That will limit the value to the least significant 5 bits.
(In other words, this works for all wraparounds that are a power of 2)

Comment: You'd normally see it written as a hex value, e.g. `0x1F`, to make it clear that this is a bitmask with the lower bits all set to 1

Comment: @canton7 or `0b1'1111`